# parcel2 error with valid JSON: "@parcel/transformer-json:" JSON5: invalid end of input at 1:1

Tags: json, configuration, parceljs

Not sure why I'm getting this error -- I'm using default configuration specs for parcel2, so it should work out of the box according to the documentation.

I've validated the JSON object and it seems to be valid, so this is a bit of a head scratcher.

None of the config/rc files are incorrectly formatted or empty, either.

Comment: FWIW, I did about an hour of searching before I figured it out. I don't see why I keep getting downvotes -- I think understanding what proper formatting for a json file is useful information.

Comment: @jasie apologies, but I'm still not clear about what's wrong with the question after reading through the post -- is it too generic? 
I got a specific error message that I found to be misleading, and after searching around for other similar issues, trying approaches that were not fruitful, I figured out _what_ was technically invalid that was different than the other suggested approaches I found.

Since this tripped me up and seemed like a gotcha different from other Q/As I'd seen on SO, I figured it's worth it to post and answer my own question. Was sharing this information wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While the JSON object was valid, the JSON file needed a carriage return (enter at the end of the file) in order to be read correctly by the parcel transformer.